# Special CSS (Flex)Grid with padding/margin and same aspect ratio

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, aspect-ratio

Hi guys normaly I'm pretty good at CSS but this reaches my limit.

I want to make a grid which Elements always have the same aspect ratio (yes the images itself does all have the same aspect ratio) and which have a padding or margin between them.

Sounds easy but I want it to look like that:
[image]

So in short it means:

1. picture 1 have to be twice as big as 2
2. all pics have to have the same aspect ratio
3. distance between the pictures should be 30px
4. mobile they should all be unter each other and on 100% width (but this was no problem)

I managed it to make it look pretty similar to what I want but never reached it exactly.

Also this should work for every screensizes. So it should be depending on the screen-width or container-width.

I tried it with flex and flex-grid but did not succeed.

Anyone already did this and knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> picture 1 have to be twice as big as 2

I think this rule can only be partially observed.

> all pics have to have the same aspect ratio

This is not possible, since a large image cannot be equal in height to two smaller images with the same aspect ratio + 30px gap.

### Result

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap: 30px;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FF0000;
  background: #333333;
}

.item--big {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item--right {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

.item__inner {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.item__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .item--big {
    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="item item--big">
    <div class="item__inner">
      <img class="item__content" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item__inner">
      <img class="item__content" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item__inner">
      <img class="item__content" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item item--big item--right">
    <div class="item__inner">
      <img class="item__content" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item__inner">
      <img class="item__content" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item__inner">
      <img class="item__content" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And same code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/YzKbgob)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this nice solution but the acpect ratio of the pictures does not change if they have another aspect ratio. So no matter which aspect ratio my pictures have it stays like it is now. Is there a way to change the aspect ratio? I think now it is twice as width as the smaler image but it should be twice as tall a the smaler ones.

Comment: @Blabla, > "Is there a way to change the aspect ratio?" — Yes, you can change it using the `padding-bottom` property of an element with a class `.item__inner`. https://prnt.sc/pcsnja . 50% - this is the ratio of height to cell width